# Export CloudFormation JSON template from GIT repository to AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a JSON file for CloudFormation in GIT repository, and I would like to push it to AWS and create a stack. Is there a best practice to achieve this task ?

Comment: We created a tool that helps do this and other things with CloudFormation https://github.com/envato/stack_master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single way of doing it. You can either deploy the template through

1. AWS Console or AWS cli
2. If you are looking for continuous deployment then  a cloud-native way would be to use CodePipeline. You can find a walkthrough [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html)
3. Another approach is to use a build server like jenkins